# ios9 The labels in UiView are merging together

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios9, xcode7

> My UiView is created from a xib file. This UiView is actually a slide
>   in menu but all the labels are merging together and collapsing
>   although the labels are distinctly visible in the xib file. This
>   happens only in ios9.

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Creating new **xib** file using **Xcode 7** solves the problem but still do not know the reason.